# table header background color change dynamically - Angular material

Tags: css, angular, html-table, angular-material

I have followed this example to implement the angular material table.

> https://stackblitz.com/angular/jejeknenmgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Here I changed the **heading color** using the below CSS code.

```
.mat-header-cell {
    background: red;
}
```

I want to pass the heading color from the component instead of the static CSS way. Is there any way to change the heading color **dynamically**?

Comment: P.S. your stackblitz link does not works

Comment: updated stackblitz link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of approach is to use [Css Var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()) and change variable value programatically in component.

**Css**

```
.mat-header-cell {
    background: var(--background-color)
}
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor()

  changeColor() {
    // set new color here
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--background-color`, 'red');
  }
}
```

So when you change variable in css, browser will change value in `.mat-header-cell` class

Another approach is to use inline style `background-color` attribute on each `mat-header-cell` item.

**In html**

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [style.background-color]="color"> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

**In component**

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  color = 'green'

 changeColor() {
   this.color = 'red';
 }

}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-color?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts)

Comment: vote up, working. I am looking for some other option.

Comment: @Shakthifuture I've editted my answer, check the second approach

Comment: Thank you, this is what I have expected.